How to get the Information Content (IC) of a sense in WordNet?
I want to get the Lin similarity between two senses using the formula and check the result using NLTK's WordNet APIs.
According to the NLTK WordNet Documentation

synset1.lin_similarity(synset2, ic): Lin Similarity: Return a score denoting how similar two word senses are, based on the Information Content (IC) of the Least Common Subsumer (most specific ancestor node) and that of the two input Synsets. The relationship is given by the equation 2 * IC(lcs) / (IC(s1) + IC(s2)).

So, I got the Lin similarity using the following NLTK code:
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn, wordnet_ic

brown_ic = wordnet_ic.ic('ic-brown.dat')
shoe = wn.synsets("shoe")[0]
cap = wn.synsets("cap")[0]

>>> shoe.lin_similarity(cap, brown_ic)
0.5185480689211218

Now I want to get the Lin similarity using the equation: 2 * IC(lcs) / (IC(s1) + IC(s2)), but I need to get the Information Content (IC) of a sense in the Brown corpus.
I tried to get IC in different ways.
Based on the definition of Information Content from [Li et al 2006], which is 1-(log(n+1)/log(N+1)) where N is the total number of words in the corpus and n is the frequency of the word:
from nltk.corpus import brown
import math

words = brown.words()
total = len(words)
def get_ic(synset):
    lemma_names = synset.lemma_names()
    freq = sum(words.count(word) for word in lemma_names)
    return 1 - (math.log(freq+1)/math.log(tot+1))

shoe_ic = get_ic(shoe)
cap_ic = get_ic(cap)

>>> shoe_ic
0.8060824738989061
>>> cap_ic
0.7930268277244025

Then I found the lowest common subsumer (LCS) and got the Lin similarity but it is wrong:
>>> cap.lowest_common_hypernyms(shoe)
[Synset('covering.n.02')]

covering = wordnet.synset('covering.n.02')

covering_ic = get_ic(covering)

>>> covering_ic
0.7518262499115436
>>> 2 * covering_ic / (shoe_ic + cap_ic)
0.9350243019743509

I also tried using brown_ic but the IC values don't seems to be the IC of the sense (which should be between 0 and 1) and differ from the sense occurrences counting:
>>> brown_ic['n'][shoe.offset()]
239.0
>>> sum(words.count(word) for word in shoe.lemma_names())
14

How can I get the IC of a sense used in lin_similarity function?
